# unity moveposition of my bullet doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the MovePosition function is not working in my script:
I have tried making it keneitic and adding force. I also have tried adding speed in the inspector. I tried adding force and making the update function a "FixedUpdate"
This is whats inside my Update function:

```
if (target != null)
             {
             Action(target);
             GameObject TemporaryBulletHandler;
             TemporaryBulletHandler = Instantiate(Sphere, Bullet_Emitter.transform.position, Bullet_Emitter.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

             Rigidbody TemporaryRigidBody;
             TemporaryRigidBody = TemporaryBulletHandler.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

             float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
             pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
             TemporaryRigidBody.MovePosition(pos);

             Destroy(TemporaryBulletHandler, 10.0f);
```

the sphere that gets created does not move.

Comment: if the above code is put in Update(), the bullet will be instantiate at the same position(Bullet_Emitter in this case) in each frame, so you won't see it's moving, it's just generated again and again in each frame. To solve this, you can put the instantiate code out of Update(), and move the bullet in Update().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a script to your bullet-prefab and add the moving-code in the FixedUpdate method of that script so every bullet handles its moving logic by itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) Rigidbody.MovePosition creates a smooth movement so it needs to be called every frame on the fixed update.

Example from the unity documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 teleportPoint;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

If what you want is to teleport the rigidbody you should take a look at [Rigidbody.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (target != null)
 {
         Action(target);
         GameObject TemporaryBulletHandler;
         TemporaryBulletHandler = Instantiate(Sphere, Bullet_Emitter.transform.position, Bullet_Emitter.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

         Rigidbody TemporaryRigidBody;
         TemporaryRigidBody = TemporaryBulletHandler.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

         float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

         TemporaryRigidBody.MovePosition ( transform.position +(target.position - transform.position ). normalized * step );

         Destroy(TemporaryBulletHandler, 10.0f);
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written